# Duplicate Class android.support

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm new to android studio and programming. I am unable to build my project as there are currently certain overlapping classes, although I am not able to identify which are. Attached below is my the code in my Gradle app. When attempting to build, a string of error messages appear, and mention duplicate classes. Please help!!!

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.finalwallpaperapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    implementation group: 'com.firebase', name: 'firebase-client-jvm', version: '2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'

    implementation 'co.gofynd.library:gravity-view:1.0'
}
```

Comment: I would like to recommend you to have sdk version 29. New version contains Androidx packages that can help you to solve this problem. I hear same problem facing from some people who having firebase project. In near future you must use Androidx so why not now, just stay updated. Let us Know after updating Android studio sdk your problem are solved. Thank you.

Comment: Show us the logcat message

Comment: hey it didnt work, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to migrate to **AndroidX**:

To do that

- Go to **Refactor**
- Go to **Migrate to AndroidX**
- Then **Migrate**

This should work